# Is it possible to style a printf output?

Tags: php, styles, printf

I would like to style a printf line.

```
printf("- %d ". $maand ." & %d " . $dag , $months, $days);
```

Lets say i want this line to be red as output. How can i accomplish this?
I think it needs to be something like this.

```
printf("<font style="color:red;">- %d ". $maand ." & %d " . $dag , $months, $days"</font>");
```

the answer of martincarlin87 seems to work but i cant make it work when im using two printf statements and want to style one of them like so:

```
<?(strtotime($date1) > strtotime($date2)) ? `printf("%d " . $maand . " & %d " . $dag , $months, $days) :  '<div class="red">'
    <?php printf("- %d ". $maand ." & %d " . $dag , $months, $days); ?>
'</div>'?>
```

Comment: two minor notes, quite OT, but might help you: try to avoid to mix Dutch and English variable names. Can be quite confusing, especially for non-dutchies. Rule of the thumb: write all your code in English. Note 2: try to avoid the shortcode syntax (`<?`). Use `<?php` in all cases. This adds clearity (debate about this starts below in 1... 2... 3...), and on some servers the shortcode is not recognized.

Comment: You're right about that. but this was written in two languages by another developer. But i would like to change all of this in the future:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="red">
    <?php printf("- %d ". $maand ." & %d " . $dag , $months, $days); ?>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

The `font` tag is deprecated in HTML5.

**edit**

Try this for your ternary `if`:

```
<?(strtotime($date1) > strtotime($date2)) ? printf("%d " . $maand . " & %d " . $dag , $months, $days) :  printf("<div class=\"red\">- %d ". $maand ." & %d " . $dag . "</div>" , $months, $days) . '' ?>
```

Comment: That seems to work thanks but when i do it within php code it doesnt seem to work. i've made an edit to my question hope you can help me with this.

Comment: It doesnt put the <div class="red"> </div> tags around the output somehow:(

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it :)

PHP:

```
<?php 

    $val1 = "Hello ";
    $val2 = "World!";

    printf('%s %s %s %s', $val1, '<span class="green">', $val2, '</span>');

?>
```

CSS:

```
.green {
    color: #8AD17A; //green
}
```

Output:

[hello world text with "world" changed to the color green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI6gw.png)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way. But you can use sprintf() which return string.

```
 echo '<font style="color:red;">'.sprintf("- %d ". $maand ." & %d " . $dag , $months, $days).'</font>';
```